# alfresco store a key value map in a single content model property

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have Alfresco community 5.2 and I need to store in the workflow model a custom property which is basically a Map. Is it possible ? and how?

If that is not possible I need to find another solution. Basically I need a custom input ftl which behaves similarly to the workflow priority input, but instead of having fixed priority int values (1,2,3) bound to priority labels (high, medium, low) I need to have dynamic int values set by the user in a Datalist.

I hope the question is clear, thanks

Comment: Store the datalist noderef on the workflow as one property, the current picked value as a second property, and have a custom FTL that dynamically fetches the datalist items when rendered?

Comment: Can you give me a detailed example? Probably I can't use it because I need also to do some maths and form updates based on user input (priority selection)

Comment: When your FTL renders, it could make a rest call to fetch the values in the datalist based on the property setting the datalist ID, then render. Highlight/select the current item based on the other property, then use client-side JS to dynamically add the rest of the fields based on the priority picked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a custom form control that gets its values from a web script. The web script can get the data from a data list. There are several examples around the web for how to create a Share form control that gets its values from a web script. Here is one: [Dynamic selectone in alfresco share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150808/dynamic-selectone-in-alfresco-share)